# understanding the logic of AND and WHERE in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, join, where-clause

I am working on Transact-SQL, Microsoft Azure.
I am trying to understand why in some join queries `WHERE` and `AND` both can be used and give the same result (or at least it seemed like the same result in my data base) and in other queries `where` doesn't work and and does.

Here, I am joining 2 tables:

```
select c.customerID, ca.addressID, ca.addressType
from salesLT.customer as c
join salesLT.customerADdress as ca
on c.customerID = ca.customerID
WHERE ca.addressType = 'Main Office';  --WHERE or AND works the same
```

This gives me what I was looking for = only the rows from customerAddress table where the type is 'Main Office'. Changing the word WHERE  to AND gives the exact same result.

Now, the query is based on the previous, but I am trying to join 3 tables. Here the `WHERE` doesn't work and I have to put an `AND`:

```
select c.customerId, c.companyName, ca.addressID, ca.addressType, a.addressLine1, a. city
from salesLT.customer as c
join salesLT.customerAddress as ca
on c.customerID = ca.customerID
WHERE ca.addressType = 'Main Office' -- error: incorrect syntax near 'join'
join salesLT.address as a
on ca.addressId = a.addressID;
```

If I change the `WHERE` to `AND` it works. Why? What is the difference between the join of 2 tables and 3? 
Thanks

Comment: The second `JOIN` should be before the `WHERE` clause

Comment: That's why you're meant to check the documentation for what the syntax of the language is before trying to write/modify code in it, rather than just sticking new bits in random places and then getting confused.

Comment: @underscore_d sticking new bits in random places is called learning through the hands. No need to help other people if it makes you so angry.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm not angry. I just don't see why so many people think trial-and-error is a good way to learn, or at least a way that others should support them with.

Comment: I don't even know why I bother answering, considering the fact that these aggressive comments are so common here, but maybe someone will learn something from this conversation. The answer to your questions lays in the question itself - you don't see why people think that a particular way is good way to learn. Try to imagine that some people think and learn different than you do, it's hard I know, but you might learn something about the people around you.. And again, if you don't want to support, just don't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change the `WHERE` to `AND` it works. Why?

Because using `and` is adding the condition to the `on` clause, but using `where` is a new clause.

Here is the full explanation: The basic syntax of a [select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement when using multiple joins is:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <table 1>
JOIN <table 2> ON <condition>
JOIN <table 3> ON <condition>
WHERE <condition>
```

This means your second query should look like this:

```
select c.customerId, c.companyName, ca.addressID, ca.addressType, a.addressLine1, a.city
from salesLT.customer as c
join salesLT.customerAddress as ca on c.customerID = ca.customerID
join salesLT.address as a on ca.addressId = a.addressID
WHERE ca.addressType = 'Main Office';
```

If you will go to the link, you will see that a select statement syntax can get much more complicated - but for now, that basic syntax should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The second `JOIN` should be before the `WHERE` clause

```
select c.customerId, c.companyName, ca.addressID, ca.addressType, a.addressLine1, a. city
from salesLT.customer as c
join salesLT.customerAddress as ca
on c.customerID = ca.customerID
join salesLT.address as a
on ca.addressId = a.addressID
WHERE ca.addressType = 'Main Office' 
;
```